# Failed to position text in SVG on iPhone with Itext 7.1.14

Tags: ios, macos, svg, itext7

I added an SVG chart to a PDF with Itext 7.1.14.
On Windows and Android, it worked normally.
However, on the iPhone or Macbook, the text is upside down and everything is on top, on the left side.
What can I do to resolve this?

Compare:

Image 1 - On Windows and Android
[image: On Windows and Android]

Image 2 - On iPhone
[image: On iPhone]

Code to generate the chart with Google Charts:

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(participantesGrafico);

        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0, 1,
            {
                calc: "stringify",
                sourceColumn: 1,
                type: "string",
                role: "annotation"
            },
        2]);

        //let fonte = 'bebas';
        let fonte = 'Arial';

        var options = {
            title: "MÉDIAS",
            width: 700,
            height: 50 * participantes.length,
            bar: { groupWidth: "80%" },
            legend: { position: "none" },
            chartArea: {
                top: 20,
                bottom: 20,
                left: 100,
                right: 20
            },
            hAxis: { textStyle: { fontName: fonte }, titleTextStyle: { fontName: fonte } },
            vAxis: { textStyle: { fontName: fonte }, titleTextStyle: { fontName: fonte } },
            titleTextStyle: { fontName: fonte },
            tooltip: { textStyle: { fontName: fonte } },
            fontName: fonte,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("graficoMedias"));
        chart.draw(view, options);
    }
```

Get in SVG. From SVG to String:

```
var grafico1 = document.getElementById('graficoMedias').getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].outerHTML;
```

SVG generated by Google Chart:

```
<svg width="700" height="200" aria-label="A chart." style="overflow: hidden;"><defs id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_0"><clipPath id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_1"><rect x="100" y="20" width="580" height="160"></rect></clipPath><filter id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_2"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"></feGaussianBlur><feOffset dx="1" dy="1"></feOffset><feComponentTransfer><feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.1"></feFuncA></feComponentTransfer><feMerge><feMergeNode></feMergeNode><feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode></feMerge></filter></defs><rect x="0" y="0" width="700" height="200" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g><text text-anchor="start" x="100" y="14.2" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">MÉDIAS</text><rect x="100" y="4" width="580" height="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect></g><g><rect x="100" y="20" width="580" height="160" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g clip-path="url(https://localhost:44322/Evento/Evento/976#_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_1)"><g><rect x="100" y="20" width="1" height="160" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="216" y="20" width="1" height="160" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="332" y="20" width="1" height="160" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="447" y="20" width="1" height="160" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="563" y="20" width="1" height="160" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="679" y="20" width="1" height="160" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="158" y="20" width="1" height="160" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ebebeb"></rect><rect x="274" y="20" width="1" height="160" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ebebeb"></rect><rect x="390" y="20" width="1" height="160" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ebebeb"></rect><rect x="505" y="20" width="1" height="160" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ebebeb"></rect><rect x="621" y="20" width="1" height="160" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ebebeb"></rect></g><g><rect x="101" y="24" width="216" height="32" stroke="#3f51b5" stroke-width="1" fill="#3f51b5"></rect><rect x="101" y="64" width="303" height="32" stroke="#3f51b5" stroke-width="1" fill="#3f51b5"></rect><rect x="101" y="104" width="506" height="32" stroke="#3f51b5" stroke-width="1" fill="#3f51b5"></rect><rect x="101" y="144" width="419" height="32" stroke="#3f51b5" stroke-width="1" fill="#3f51b5"></rect></g><g><rect x="100" y="20" width="1" height="160" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#333333"></rect></g><g><rect x="317" y="40" width="0" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#999999"></rect><rect x="404" y="80" width="0" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#999999"></rect><rect x="607" y="120" width="0" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#999999"></rect><rect x="520" y="160" width="0" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#999999"></rect></g></g><g></g><g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="100.5" y="194.2" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">0</text></g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="216.3" y="194.2" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">2</text></g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="332.1" y="194.2" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">4</text></g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="447.9" y="194.2" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">6</text></g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="563.7" y="194.2" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">8</text></g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="679.5" y="194.2" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">10</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="88" y="44.575" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">Chromium</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="88" y="84.325" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">Edge</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="88" y="124.075" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">Firefox</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="88" y="163.825" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">Opera</text></g></g><g><g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="313" y="44.2" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">3.74</text><rect x="290" y="34" width="23" height="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect></g></g><g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="400" y="84.2" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">5.25</text><rect x="377" y="74" width="23" height="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect></g></g><g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="603" y="124.2" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">8.75</text><rect x="580" y="114" width="23" height="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect></g></g><g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="516" y="164.2" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">7.25</text><rect x="493" y="154" width="23" height="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect></g></g></g></g><g></g></svg>
```

C# code:

```
byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(grafico1);
MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream(b);
Image i = SvgConverter.ConvertToImage(ms2, document.GetPdfDocument());
document.Add(i);
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? The problem may be caused by using styles instead of attributes in SVG

Comment: Michael Rovinsky, thanks for interacting.
I updated the post with the codes I used so far.

Comment: I took your generated SVG and removed unused <defs> from it. Please take the result from a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/mef63sd2/ and let me know if the problem persists

Comment: Unfortunately the problem remains.